# Python statsmodels Probit and Logit produce an error, while OLS works fine?

Tags: python, machine-learning, model, regression, statsmodels

My dependent variable is full of 0s and 1s. It is in the train_label pandas dataframe, with the column name 'Offer Accepted'.

```
train_label.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 14400 entries, 0 to 14399
Data columns (total 1 columns):
 #   Column          Non-Null Count  Dtype
---  ------          --------------  -----
 0   Offer Accepted  14400 non-null  int64
dtypes: int64(1)
memory usage: 112.6 KB
```

My independent variables are contained in the train_features dataframe. Some are categorical (0 or 1; 1, 2, or 3), and some are regular.

```
train_features.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 14400 entries, 0 to 14399
Data columns (total 28 columns):
 #   Column                      Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------                      --------------  -----  
 0   Customer Number             14400 non-null  float64
 1   Reward                      14400 non-null  float64
 2   Mailer Type                 14400 non-null  float64
 3   Income Level                14400 non-null  float64
 4   # Bank Accounts Open        14400 non-null  float64
 5   Overdraft Protection        14400 non-null  float64
 6   Credit Rating               14400 non-null  float64
 7   # Credit Cards Held         14400 non-null  float64
 8   # Homes Owned               14400 non-null  float64
 9   Household Size              14400 non-null  float64
 10  Own Your Home               14400 non-null  float64
 11  Average Balance             14400 non-null  float64
 12  Q1 Balance                  14400 non-null  float64
 13  Q2 Balance                  14400 non-null  float64
 14  Q3 Balance                  14400 non-null  float64
 15  Q4 Balance                  14400 non-null  float64
 16  Balance*Income Level        14400 non-null  float64
 17  Q1*Income Level             14400 non-null  float64
 18  Q2*Income Level             14400 non-null  float64
 19  Q3*Income Level             14400 non-null  float64
 20  Q4*Income Level             14400 non-null  float64
 21  Balance*Credit              14400 non-null  float64
 22  Q1*Credit                   14400 non-null  float64
 23  Q2*Credit                   14400 non-null  float64
 24  Q3*Credit                   14400 non-null  float64
 25  Q4*Credit                   14400 non-null  float64
 26  Bank Accounts*Income Level  14400 non-null  float64
 27  Bank Accounts*Credit        14400 non-null  float64
dtypes: float64(28)
memory usage: 3.1 MB
```

When I run:

```
from statsmodels.api import OLS
OLS(train_label, train_features).fit().summary()
```

It produces the desired table.
My Adj. R-squared (uncentered) is low at 0.093, so I would like to try a Probit or Logit model.

However, when I try to run

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
sm.Probit(train_label, train_features).fit().summary()
```

I get the Lin Alg: Singular Matrix error.

When I run

```
from statsmodels.api import OLS
OLS(train_label, train_features[2:3]).fit().summary()
```

I get ValueError: The indices for endog and exog are not aligned
I have tried this code,
`train_label.reindex(train_features.index)`
but it does not change anything.

Any idea how I can run a probit regression?

Comment: If I run: sm.Probit(train_label, train_features['Reward']).fit().summary() then I do get a working result. However, it only works with one variable at a time

Comment: I guess your train_features is singular and has collinear columns. search for "dummy variable trap"